# ASP.NET Core MVC Group by query with LINQ

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I am trying to query the country column from one of my table and trying to group them so that one country name appears only once.

The controller code is

```
ViewBag.Countries = (from pT in _context.InfoProducts
                                 group pT by new { pT.Country } into g
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Country = g.Key.Country
                                 }).ToList();
```

In my view I am trying to show this list of countries in a dropdown like this

```html
<div class=" form-group">
    @Html.Label("Country")
    <div class="col-md-12 ">
    @Html.DropDownList("Country", new SelectList(ViewBag.Countries, "Country"), "Select Country", new { @class = "col-form-label col-md-12 label-align" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is though it is returning the expected names of the countries, the result is generating as a key, value pair something like

```
{Country = USA}
{Country = Canada}
```

The HTML generated copied from inspect element is given below

```html
<select class="col-form-label col-md-12 label-align" id="Country" name="Country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option>{ Country = USA}</option>
    <option>{ Country = Canada}</option>
</select>
```

How can I get only the country name in the dropdown instead of the result I am currently getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using group by, it sounds like [distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netcore-3.1) would be a better fit:

```
_context.InfoProducts.Select(x => x.Country).Distinct().ToList();
```

This will give you back a list of strings to use, which won't give you the key-value pair problem you're currently having.

One more thing, when you use `new SelectList(ViewBag.Countries, "Country")` this overload of `SelectList`'s constructor will try to set the value of `Country` as the selected item, but this doesn't exist in your list, so `Select Country` will always appear as selected. If you want that to select an actual country, then it would have to look something like:

```
new SelectList(ViewBag.Countries, "Canada")
```

where you would fetch `Canada` from the data for the current product.